# retrieve a file through .net webservice

Tags: .net, web-services

In .net web services is there a way where the file name can be sent in the SOAP request and the service returns the File itself as attachment in the SOAP response. I was thinking if the file can only be returned as a filestream object or some sort of .net I/O related object but not as an attachment. I was asked to check if this can be done? Any thoughts or comments?

Comment: sorry, i didn't understood *how* exactly you want file sent?

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by `attachment`? A SOAP response represents XML encoded data which is sent to the client. Binary structures such as `byte[]` will be [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded and sent in the response body. So the following method should do the job:

```
[WebMethod]
public byte[] GetFile(string filename) 
{
    // Add security checks, etc... as such method is begging for hacks
    return File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
}
```

Also you should probably consider using [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) because ASP.NET web services are considered now as deprecated technology. There are also protocols over HTTP such as [MTOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-mtom/) that support optimized binary data transmission over the wire.

Comment: +1, Keep in mind, Base64 encoded string of a file could be **HUGE**.

Comment: Yeap, that's why I mentioned `MTOM`.